# Call hidden (non virtual) method of derived class from base

Tags: c++, inheritance, compile-time, member-hiding

Is there a way (templates, macros anything else) to substitute a call to *hidden_in_derived* from *common* method at ***compile time***, so that instance of Derived calls it's own *hidden_in_derived* (***without*** making *hidden_in_derived* virtual in Base) ?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    void common() {
        // some calls to other methods
        hidden_in_derived();
        // yet some calls to other methods
    }

    void hidden_in_derived() {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void hidden_in_derived() {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.common(); // want hidden_in_derived (prints "B") here somehow ?

}
```

Comment: *without making it virtual* - well, that's the whole point of *virtual* functions.

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why can't you make `hidden_in_derived` virtual?

Comment: Sorry, misread the code initially. Comment removed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've read about seams technique to inject testing calls to some third-party library, let's say in C (not sure if I got it right, though). It suggest adding virtual methods with the same name as third-party library ones and overriding them in derived classes in tests. In base you use scope operator (::) to resolve to real third party library code . So I was hoping to look for some solution avoid virtual somehow - templates or such ?

Comment: If `hidden_in_derived()` is not a `virtual` function of `Base`, then `Base::common()` needs to manually work out the ACTUAL type of the object `this`.   That's not possible unless `Base` carries some information that is set uniquely for every derived class AND the implementation of `Base::common()` has information about every possible derived class and is updated whenever a new class is derived.    The cost of doing all that (and the likelihood of errors, due to forgetting to keep `Base::common()` properly updated) means it would be easier to make `hidden_in_derived()` virtual.

Comment: Do you need the derived classes to actually share a common base? CRTP may work if you don't. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/xVcW2T

Comment: @Peter, any chance you can point me to some example ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, please see my comment on seam testing technique above.

Comment: You might hide Base::common in Derived, too. Be aware that then `Base* b = new Derived(); b->common();` still will print `A`, though, as common is not virtual either.

Comment: @Aconcagua, I forgot to mention that there are calls to other methods in common, besides a call to hidden_in_derived(). So I guess hiding common in derived will not work.

Comment: @psb I assumed already that you would have to re-implement entire `common` then. On the other hand, agree, if there are private functions/variables inolved, bad luck... Do you have any specific reason for avoiding virtuality by all means?

Comment: @Aconcagua reduce calling of virtual functions overhead, since I expect hidden_in_derived() to be called a lot (but I might be overthinking here, basically just willing to know my options).

Comment: The CRTP pattern as mentioned already could be an option then. If you *do* need a common base, then you could have the template as an intermediate class inheriting from the common base. But that's pretty much effort, the virtual function is *much* simpler. Are you sure that the virtual call will be of that much relevance at all? Have you profiled? You might just be optimising prematurely while your bottleneck is at a totally different place...

Comment: @Aconcagua I totally agree on a point of 'optimising prematurely'. Mainly curious about techniques available.  This CRTP pattern seems like what I really need. I just don't get what TedLyngmo meant with: "Do you need the derived classes to actually share a common base? CRTP may work if you don't". His example seems to do what I need.

Comment: No each base in my example is a unique base so Derived1 and Derived2 would have different bases.

Comment: @psb Beware that going the CRTP route requires all your relevant source code to be in headers. It works because the compiler will create a different `common()` implementation for every different `Derived`, but it can obviously only do that if it sees the `common()` source code at the point where you instantiate `Base<Derived>`.

Answer (score 0):

Make it virtual, then you can even use Base class ptr: https://wandbox.org/permlink/tF5Cb4fE5jEhG5Ru

Or just like you did with an object:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/W2EJGXwioXjqd1Zx

Comment: You can use funtion ptr or std::function and assign it with a lambda during construction of an object. Derived is constructed after Base so it should always call "most derived" implementation.
https://wandbox.org/permlink/SCPmaQ4g5PoQzPRi

Comment: ```but hidden_in_derived()``` is virtual in base class anyway, right ? There is a  CRTP pattern metioned in the comments to question. It seems to do what I need.

Comment: wandbox.org/permlink/SCPmaQ4g5PoQzPRi  looks interesting. I have no idea how lambda internally works. Wouldn't be there any kind of additional runtime overhead involved in doing this (akin to virtual methods) ?

Comment: Lambda is the same as creating struct with `operator()` which is calling body of lambda. Pointer to this is passed, there are no virtual methods used.
Look here to test it: https://cppinsights.io/s/cd71574c

Comment: @psb The lambda itself is as cheap as a normal method call (the compiler can inline it because it knows everything). However, `std::function` does type erasure internally, which definitely involves a virtual method call. Replacing a virtual method by a `std::function` is extremely pointless and almost surely a performance pessimization (good compilers might manage to inline through all the `std::function` abstraction, but in that case they could just do the same with virtual methods in the first place. And yes, you are prematurely optimizing - profile your approaches, then decide.)

Comment: @bialy Answers should be just as self-contained as questions. Links to external resources can expire, retracting any worth from your answer. Some people might have trouble with your link even if it still exists, with similar effect for them...